# Calculate the difference between specific events in dataframe

Tags: r

I have three different types of events (`Pass`, `RHM` and `REM`), see example below;

| Event | Start |
| --- | --- |
| RHM | 668.043 |
| Pass | 668.873 |
| Pass | 675.213 |
| RHM | 675.383 |
| REM | 678.900 |
| Pass | 680.163 |
| Pass | 683.543 |

Now I want to know the difference between the start time of a specific pass to another even, depending on the event type. More specifically; for each `Pass` I want to know what is the difference between the current `Pass` and the previous `Pass`, the previous `RHM` and the previous `REM`.

So for the first pass, which is the second row in the dataframe (start = 668.873), the difference with the previous `Pass` is NaN (because there is none before), the difference with the previous `RHM` is 668.873-668.043 = 0.83, and the difference with the previous `REM` is again NaN because there is none. Ideally this would result in the following result;

| Event | Time since last `Pass` | Time since last `RHM` | Time since last `REM` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pass | NaN | 0.830 | NaN |
| Pass | 6.340 | 7.170 | NaN |
| Pass | 4.950 | 4.780 | 1.263 |
| Pass | 3.380 | 8.160 | 4.643 |

To make it more complex, the dataframe has two extra variables, to loop the above over; `Category` and `Situation`;

| Category | Situation | Event | Start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 1 | RHM | 668.043 |
| R1 | 1 | Pass | 668.873 |
| R1 | 1 | Pass | 675.213 |
| R1 | 1 | RHM | 675.383 |
| R1 | 1 | REM | 678.900 |
| R1 | 1 | Pass | 680.163 |
| R1 | 1 | Pass | 683.543 |
| R2 | 2 | RHM | 668.043 |
| R2 | 2 | Pass | 668.873 |
| R2 | 2 | Pass | 675.213 |
| R2 | 2 | RHM | 675.383 |
| R2 | 3 | REM | 678.900 |
| R2 | 3 | Pass | 680.163 |
| R2 | 3 | Pass | 683.543 |

I have used the current code, which works for 1 situation, but it needs to start over for each Situation. and I don't know how to do that. I was thinking of using `dplyr` but don't know how to combine it with a for-loop.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  
    # PASSES
    # look in rows above the current row and search for last row containing "Pass"
    previousPasses <- which(x$Event[1:i - 1] == "Pass")
    # get last of these passes
    lastPass <- previousPasses[length(previousPasses)]
    # if there are no previous passes, then leave the TimeLastPass column blank
    if (length(lastPass) == 0) {
        x$TimeLastPass[i] <- NaN
    } else {
        # otherwise, fill in the TimeLastPass column with the time of the last pass
        x$TimeLastPass[i] <- round(x$Start[lastPass] - x$Start[i],2)
    }
    
    ### REM
    # look in rows above the current row and search for last row containing "REM"
    previousREMs <- which(x$Event[1:i - 1] == "Referential Eye Movement")
    # get last of these REMs
    lastREM <- previousREMs[length(previousREMs)]
    # if there are no previous REMs, then leave the TimeLastREM column blank
    if (length(lastREM) == 0) {
        x$TimeLastREM[i] <- NaN
    } else {
        # otherwise, fill in the TimeLastREM column with the time of the last REM
        x$TimeLastREM[i] <- round(x$Start[lastREM] - x$Start[i], 2)
    }

    ### RHM
    # look in rows above the current row and search for last row containing "RHM"
    previousRHMs <- which(x$Event[1:i - 1] == "Referential Head Movement")
    # get last of these RHMs
    lastRHM <- previousRHMs[length(previousRHMs)]
    # if there are no previous RHMs, then leave the TimeLastRHM column blank
    if (length(lastRHM) == 0) {
        x$TimeLastRHM[i] <- NaN
    } else {
        # otherwise, fill in the TimeLastRHM column with the time of the last RHM
        x$TimeLastRHM[i] <- round(x$Start[lastRHM] - x$Start[i],2)
    }
}
```

Comment: This would become much easier to understand and code if you first `split` (or the tidyverse equivalent `group_by`) the data in the wide form of your third example by Category and Situation. Then you would have the data partitioned so you could concentrate on the interior algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, as described in the comment above, would be using `tidyverse`.

In this case, you have 3 types of events. You can create 3 columns for those events, containing either the `Start` time, or NA (missing).

Then, using `fill` you can propagate down the `Start` values, so it retains the latest value to use later for differences.

The `filter` will only keep rows that have "Pass" events as in the example. For "Pass" just take differences with `diff`. For the other columns, you can use `mutate` and `across`.

If you want to do this independently for each `Category` and `Situation` use `group_by` at the beginning, such as `group_by(Category, Situation)` after `df` in the pipe.

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(RHM = ifelse(Event == "RHM", Start, NA),
         Pass = ifelse(Event == "Pass", Start, NA),
         REM = ifelse(Event == "REM", Start, NA)) |>
  fill(RHM, Pass, REM) |>
  filter(Event == "Pass") |>
  mutate(Pass = c(NA, diff(Start)),
         across(c(RHM, REM), ~ Start - .))
```

**Output**

```
  Event   Start  RHM Pass   REM
1  Pass 668.873 0.83   NA    NA
2  Pass 675.213 7.17 6.34    NA
3  Pass 680.163 4.78 4.95 1.263
4  Pass 683.543 8.16 3.38 4.643
```